# Node.js REST API to fetch data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to create a REST API using Node.js that would fetch the last N rows of a MongoDB collection. This is my current code:

```
var express     =   require("express");
var app         =   express();
var bodyParser  =   require("body-parser");
var router      =   express.Router();
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var db;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended" : false}));

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sample", function(err, database) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  db = database;

  // the Mongo driver recommends starting the server here because most apps *should* fail to start if they have no DB.  If yours is the exception, move the server startup elsewhere.
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  db.collection("samplecollection").find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        }
      else {
        res.end();
      }
    });
  }).limit(10,function(e,d){});
});

app.use('/',router);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to PORT 3000");
```

This is successfully printing out all of the contents of the database on the server console (Whenever the client makes a get request). However, how do I give this JSON information to the client making the GET call instead in an efficient way (and one that supports the situation where the client can add a parameter N that would only fetch the last N rows of the database). I looked into Mongoose and that seemed pretty solid but in my case I already have a pre-existing database and collection so wasn't sure if that was the best route for this task.

If you need any more info or clarification, feel free to let me know! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `res.end`, you would use `res.send` and send the response back to the front end.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  db.collection("samplecollection").find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        var response = {
              statusCode: 200,
              headers:  { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              body:    JSON.parse(doc)
            }
        res.send(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

To get the last N records of a collection, you could use a combination of `sort` and `limit`. First, sort on a specific field such as date in ascending/descending order and then limit the results to whatever N is. Something like this:

db.collection.find({ query }).sort({ key: 1 }).limit(N)

**UPDATE:**

Based on our ongoing comment conversation, here is an example of how I have successfully sent data back to the client. This does not include the limit or anything fancy.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var db = require('./config/db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  db.find({}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.send(500, 'Something Went wrong with Retrieving data');
    } else {
      // console.log(data[0]);
      res.json(data);
    }
  });

});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on port: ', port);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in the if(doc) statement? Not the else statement then?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have updated the answer to also include how I would go about getting the last N records.

Comment: So I updated my initial post to include how I was trying the limit earlier but it doesnt seem to be working. It seems to be following the format you mentioned in the post.

Comment: So this code somewhat works, however, I get an error after the first JSON object gets sent: Can't set headers after they are sent. This is on the    `res.send(response);` line.

Comment: hmm, first, I'm looking into if the `.limit` should be somewhere else when using MongoClient, but I don't think so. Second, instead of returning a full response object, just return the `JSON.parse(body)`

Comment: I tried just sending the doc but the new line `res.send(doc)` is also resulting  in the same issue.

Comment: Can you remove `next` from your code? It may/may not be causing the headers to get written (I know, I know, its in the error handling). Either way, as we are dealing with one route here, I don't see the use and may be nothing, but eliminating a possible cause is good.

Comment: I removed next but still same issues unfortunately.

Comment: I'm working on it. I have a local test server setup to figure out whats going on. I'll post when I get home and test a little more. It is something simple I bet

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I'll continue to look into it for now.

Comment: I just came across a basic example of an old server I worked on before, and it works just fine. Can you try `res.json(doc)` instead of `res.send()`?

Comment: Same issue...something must be wrong with my environment then.

Comment: Got it now...added another callback function. Added it as an answer

Comment: Had a hunch it was the for each loop. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up fixing my issue. Changed my get statement to this:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

db.collection("samplecollection", function(err, collection){
    collection.find({}).limit(10).toArray(function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
  })
});
});
```